# PrimeFaces 4 selectItems itemLabelEscaped

Tags: primefaces

Is there a way to apply `itemLabelEscaped` as default `true` for all `f:selectItems` in the entire application without making code change every where in code?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no simple config like way as far as I know. Overriding the renderer of this component will work, though it is up to you to code that